# What normal JavaScript functions are available in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

My question is best illustrated by example.

I'm attempting to begin writing some regression tests in CasperJS. However, the website requires authentication (not Basic HTTP Auth), so I'll be using the setup option function to log in for the duration of the tests. However,  I don't want to hardcode this into the script for obvious reasons. My solution is to read in the credentials from `stdin` using `system`. However, I am trying to use `readLine` since I don't know the length ahead of time. This captures a newline at the end. I don't want the newline so I'm trying to trim it off the end. However, calling `username.slice(0,-1)` results in a crash, I think.

It doesn't actually display any error, it just hangs.

Thus, my question is what ***IS*** available in PhantomJS that we would be used to having in a normal JS environment? Is there a list somewhere?

Bonus points if you know a way to configure CasperJS in the scenario of a login.

EDIT: Test code, as requested. On my machine, it does nothing after you submit the username.

```
var system = require('system')
system.stdout.write("Please input username: ")
username = system.stdin.readLine()
user = username.slice(0,-1) // or trim()
system.stdout.write("You entered: " + user);
```

Comment: What is wrong with `username.trim()`?

Comment: It hangs, just like `slice`.

Comment: `slice` is definitely available on strings. Chances are that `username` is not a string. Show us your code.

Comment: I tried it with different versions with `slice`. 1.8.2 doesn't have `system.stdout`, 1.9.0 reads `username` with the ending newline, so the output is actually correct, 1.9.7 & 2.0.1 are missing one letter at the end of `username`.

Comment: @ArtjomB., see, I don't get any output after line two in my example. Do you?

Comment: Yes, I do get output. `Please input username: asdf` and `You entered: asd` for 2.0.1. Then it doesn't exit, because there is no `phantom.exit()` in the code.

Comment: Works in 2.0 as well (just built it). I'm not sure why 1.9 wasn't working.