# npm installs not available in CasperJS

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, node-modules

According to the [CasperJS Documentation](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_modules.html), I should just be able to install things through `npm` and then require them in my CasperJS scripts for use (since 1.1 apparently, and I'm using 1.1.0-beta3)

However, this doesn't work for me and I get the error "CasperError: Can't find module ModuleName", where I've tried `read`, `underscore`, `readline`, etc. And, they've all been installed using `sudo npm install ModuleName`.

Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: For reference, this is related, but not identical, to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219035/what-normal-javascript-functions-are-available-in-phantomjs?noredirect=1#comment46648600_29219035).

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue with CasperJS 1.1.0-beta3 + PhantomJS 1.9.7 or current CasperJS master + PhantomJS 2.0 on windows.

Comment: I am using CasperJS 1.1.0-beta3 + PhantomJS 2.0.1-dev on Linux.